# Block-quoting a list: where to put the citation?

Tags: citations, writing-style, quotation

Suppose I write something like this

> Jones categorises things as follows:
>
> - little things
> - big things
> - medium-size things

... where the entire list is a verbatim quotation from Jones. The list is block-quoted (i.e., it is indented, but there are no quotation marks). **How can I make it clear that the entire list comes from Jones's paper?** If I put the citation on the last item of the list, it might look like the citation is only for the last item.

The best solution I can think of is to clarify the situation in the surrounding text, something like the example below. Is this reasonable?

> Jones categorises things as shown below. (Entire list is from Jones, 2015.)
>
> - little things
> - big things
> - medium-size things

Comment: Is the list a verbatim quote or just repeating Jones’ categories with your own words?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft In this case t's a verbatim quote. But I've also encountered this problem with lists that I have paraphrased, so it would be good to have answers for each scenario.

Comment: btw, if you decide to keep the sentence, add the article _the_, as in: _The entire list..._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter whether you quote the list verbatim or paraphrase it, I'm quite sure you don't need to make it a big deal. Quoting a list of bullets isn't really quoting long pieces of text that would need a note about being a verbatim quote; I would say it's more like quoting a theorem in maths. I would therefore go for one of the following:

> Jones [Jon15] categorizes things as follows: **LIST**
>
> Jones categorizes things as follows [Jon15]: **LIST**
>
> (Jones, 2015) categorizes things as follows: **LIST**
>
> etc.

Use the one that is consistent with your citation habits.