# How to properly add attribution to a paraphrased list?

Tags: citations, writing-style

This question is similar to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61591/block-quoting-a-list-where-to-put-the-citation), however in my case, I have paraphrased the list of the original work.

I'm paraphrasing a list of a paper like this

> A five-step model is proposed in [123]:
>
> 1. (Paraphrase of step 1 from [123])
> 2. (Paraphrase of step 2 from [123])
> 3. etc.

The original source is a numbered list as well, but I have summarized each point to simplify it for my readers and make the connections to my work clearer. I got feedback that it is not obvious whether the way I've written is a verbatim quote of the list or not. How can I clarify that I have paraphrased the list entries? My university has no explicit style guide, I'm usually orienting myself on the IEEE style.

I thought of something like

> A five-step model is proposed in [123], which can be summarized as:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion should be fine. It is clear, avoids plagiarism, and lets you use wording more appropriate for the current usage.

Just be accurate in your paraphrasing, as always.